# How to insert OneDimensional Array Elements to TwoDimensional Array if OneDim Array length exceeding the length of TwoDim Array's rows or columns

Tags: c#, multidimensional-array

I have been trying to insert the values of OneDim Array to a TwoDimensional Array, but have a problem with the length of OneDim Array. So what is actually happening:

Let's say I have a TwoDim Array  twoDimArray[2,2] and OneDim Array oneDimArray[3] when I try to add elements from the OneDim to TwoDim my app crash

The reason why it's happening is coz of the length of OneDim Array, it's longer than a row or column of the TwoDim Array... the remaining element should go to another row or column of the TwoDim Array. If in this case, I set oneDimArray[2] or less everything will work fine.

So how can I get the remaining elements to another row/column of the TwoDim Array?

This is my code

```
Console.Write("Add number of rows: ");
        int redovi = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        Console.Write("Add number of columns: ");
        int kolone = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

        int[,] parking = new int[redovi, kolone];
        for (int i = 0; i < parking.GetLength(0); i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(" ");
            for (int j = 0; j < parking.GetLength(1); j++)
            {
                parking[i,j] = 0;
                Console.Write("\t" + parking[i, j]);
            }
            Console.WriteLine();
        }

        Console.Write("\nHow many lots you want to use: ");
        int[] parkingMesta = new int[int.Parse(Console.ReadLine())];
        
        for (int i = 0; i < parkingMesta.Length; i++)
        {
            parking[i, parkingMesta[i]] = 1;
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < parking.GetLength(0); i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(" ");
            for (int j = 0; j < parking.GetLength(1); j++)
            {
                Console.Write("\t" + parking[i, j]);
            }
            Console.WriteLine();
        }
        Console.ReadLine();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, your second `for` loop needs to look something like this.

```cs
for (int i = 0; i < parkingMesta.Length; i++)
{
    parking[i % parking.GetLength(0), i / parking.GetLength(1)] = 1;
}
```

However, you still need to make sure `parkingMesta.Length` isn't greater than the total number of lots.

Comment: amazing man! that's exactly what I was looking for! And of course, I will add an if statement in case someone wants more lots than exists! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `Array`, use `List`. A list will dynamically grow based on the elements.

See:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1?view=net-5.0

Comment: I know about List, but this is for the course that I am studying so I have to use Array :/

Comment: I guess I don't understand your assignment: you must use an array, but arrays cannot be resized in dot net, and you must resize it...? Or am I misunderstanding?

Comment: I am not sure if I have to resize it or just move the remaining elements to the next row of the TwoDim Array. If I can place 4 elements in each row of the TwoDim Array, but my OneDim Array has 5 elements my question is how to place the 5th element to the next row of TwoDim Array